# Uncaught Error: "category" is not a registered scale

Tags: reactjs, charts

I am trying to implement React char but getting this error, I search and follow decumentation but couldn't find the solution.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';


const BarChart = () => {

  return (
      <div>
        <Bar data={{
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BarChart;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);

const BarChart = () => { ... your code ... }
```

As described in https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.0/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc you need to register all the components you're going to use.
The above code just registers everything.

Check out the link for all available components you can register.

Comment: Still working, Im using it in nextjs13